# Angular redirect to route after http call

Tags: angular

home.component.html

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" initial scale ="1.0" user 
scalable="no">

 <body>

 <div class="container">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="form_bg">
 <form>
   <h2 class="text-center">Login Page</h2>
  <br/>
  Enter Username : <input type="text" class="form-control" 
  [(ngModel)]="username" name="username">

  <a [routerLink]="['/profile']" class="btn btn-primary" 
  (click)="findProfile()">Submit</a>

  </form>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </body>


this.profileService.getProfileRepos().subscribe(repos => {
    console.log(repos);
    this.repos = repos;
  })    
 }

ngOnInit() {
}


 }
```

When I am entering the username and click on submit then it is redirecting me to another page. But it shows nothing on that page.

Comment: `<form>` should be `<form novalidate>`

Answer (score 1):

Although I strongly oppose your site asking for login details of another website, here is what you are doing wrong

```
 <a [routerLink]="['/profile']" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="findProfile()">Submit</a>
```

should be

```
 <a class="btn btn-primary" (click)="findProfile()">Submit</a>
```

`onclick` cannot be used to bind to functions on component.ts in angular, you must use `(click)`. Also, you redirect to `/profile` upon click using `[routerLink]`

And in the `findProfile` function, you should navigate to profile once it is resolved.

Also, consider using RxJs operators like `flatmap`, `combineLatest` etc in `findProfile` since you have multiple subscriptions in the functions, and its unclear when you should do the redirect.

Comment: I have made the changes that you suggested . now , when i am clicking on login , it is redirecting me to another page and that page is showing deatails of user in console only . How to  show it on main screen .

Comment: try `<div *ngIf='repos'>{{repos | json }}<div>` on your template. Http calls are asynchronous in angular

Answer (score 0):

@rjv agree with you.

Please try to remove all content of profile.html and just print `<h1>hello</h1>`
check if its working or not if its working than your condition is not satisfied.

Please call method inside ngOnInit() method of profile.component.ts because on that once profile will get than html will render.